# glob module is refereed from system package instead of python venv

Tags: python-import, glob, python-venv

While trying to import glob in a python venv environment, it is referring to the system package and not the virtual environment even though pandas module is referring to the virtual environment.

I am using python 3.8 and I created a virtual environment using python venv :

`cd trial_3`

`python3 -m venv trial_3_env`

On trying to use glob module (which i haven't yet installed in the environment), I can see that it is not throwing any error, but using the glob module from the system packages.

Please find the screenshot showing the same below:

```
(trial_3_env) anitta@vinjohn:~/Desktop/Study_Data_Engineering/virtualenv_trial/trial_3$ pip freeze
numpy==1.23.4
pyspark==3.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.6
six==1.16.0
(trial_3_env) anitta@vinjohn:~/Desktop/Study_Data_Engineering/virtualenv_trial/trial_3$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import glob
>>> glob.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.8/glob.py'
>>>
```

I tried checking this behavior with pandas module, but they are working as expected and throw error while importing when I have not preinstalled them in my system.

```
(trial_3_env) anitta@vinjohn:~/Desktop/Study_Data_Engineering/virtualenv_trial/trial_3$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>>
```

Could someone let me know the cause of globs behavior ? and if such scenario can occur for other modules as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No screenshots of text or code. Edit your question to copy-paste the text or code.

Comment: `glob` is from Python's standard library, while `pandas` is a "_pip_-installed" 3rd party library.

Comment: @sinoroc i have edited my question to show the code text instead of the image. Hope you can see it now. Also, from your comment, you mean to say that the if a package belongs to python standard library then it will be pointed to the system python interpreter path and not the python interpreter inside in the virtual env ?

Comment: The python interpreter in your virtual environment is just a symlink to the system one. A virtual environment has its own site-packages set relative to this symlink location, this is where pip packages will be installed as @sinoroc says. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) for more details about how the module search path is set. But a virtual environment does not have its own system packages.

Comment: Oh! that explains it. will check out the link you provided for more details. Thanks :) @ChrisD Could you post it as an answer, so that I can close this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChrisD and @sinoroc answers helped me. standard libraries of venv python interpreter are referenced from the system python interpreter path itself and venv folder doesn't have any python standard libraries stored inside.